# How do I associate ESC key to return/cancel on a C# inputbox?

Tags: c#, inputbox

I have an inputbox that is receiving a password, but if I press ESC it's the same thing of pressing ENTER for some reason, I would like that ESC have could have the same action as cancel/close box here.

Does anyone have a solution or has been through the same problem?

```
 private void configuraçõesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String result = "";
        InputBox.getPasswordInputBox("Senha", "Digite a senha", ref result);

        if ("xxxx".Equals(result))
        {
            new fConfiguracao().ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Senha incorreta");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does it mean for an inputBox to close? Do you mean a TextBox? Do you mean for it to disappear or remove all text?

Comment: winforms, WPF, web ? where is that "inputbox"? please tag question

Comment: it's windowsform, it's the inputbox component, I want it to close only
I added the code

Comment: Do you have a link to the inputbox documentation? I can't find anything on it with a google search. Or perhaps it is a custom form you made?

Comment: I saw in the inputbox documentation but nothing helped. Thanks friend, I will try another way.

Comment: Where did the `InputBox` component come from? It is not standard in C#.

Comment: @NetMage, there's a pop up dialog InputBox to prompt user for a value. Need to add reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` and then you do `InputBox("Question?","Title","Default Text");`. The control used by OP might be a derived version or something created from scratch, as getPasswordInputBox doesn't even follow naming convention. It should start with uppercase.

Comment: That's why I don't think it is the `InputBox` from VB.